# Time Format so there's only 4 digits with a ":" in the middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-formatting

I want the concatenated NSString I have to be output in the format "00:00", the 0s being the digits in the concatenated string. And if there are not enough characters in the NSString, the other digits are made to be 0.

And if there are more than 4 digits than I want to only have the furthest right digits.
I have done this in Java before, I am assuming it's possible in Objective-C as well.

```
UIButton *button = sender;
NSString *concatenated = [self.input stringByAppendingString: button.titleLabel.text];
self.input = concatenated;
self.userOutput.text = self.input;
```

For example, I might get "89" as my concatenated string. I then want, self.input = 00:89.

OR

if I get 89374374 from my concatenated string, I then want self.input = 43:74.

I hope I am being clear

Comment: What is `self.input` and what's in `titleLabel.text`?

Comment: self.input is a global variable, that is a NSString. And .titleLabel.text is just one digit(0-9)

Comment: Right, but how do they fit into the result you want? Your question is not very clear. Give some examples of what you have and how you want it to end up.

Comment: I tried my best to give some examples with my edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method should give the desired output:

```
- (NSString *)getFormattedTimeStringFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    int input = [string intValue];
    int mins = input % 100;
    input /= 100;
    int hours = input % 100;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", hours, mins];
}
```

You can use this by calling

```
self.input = [self getFormattedTimeStringFromString:concatenated];
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *dateTimeStr = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: This is fine for an `NSDate` but the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with an `NSDate`. It's about building up a string from other strings.

Comment: yea I'm not sure how this helps, but I am trying to convert my NSString to  NSdate right now to see if your solution works

Comment: @tnek316 in that case create a date from your string, then create a string from the date. You create dates from a string using `[df dateFromString:str]`. Obviously the dateFormat will be different.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ([concatenated length] == 2) {

        self.input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:%@",concatenated];
}
else
{
        NSString *test = [concatenated substringFromIndex:[concatenated length] -4];
        self.input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",[test substringToIndex:2],[test substringFromIndex:[test length]-2]];

}
```

Please try above code it will fail if `[concatenated length]` is 3 or 1 , modify it accordingly